# How to link MVC application with membership provider and data model in different class libraries together?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-membership, libraries

I have 3 class libraries and `ASP.MVC 4` web application.

1. Library - Base data model (users, roles, etc...)

```cs
public class User
{
  public int ID { get; set; }
  public string Comments { get; set; }....
}
```

2. Library - Extended data model (Partners, Products) - this can vary with the different web app.
3. Library - Membership provider.

I create my `DBContext` in the MVC app, as only there I know which `DBSet` I need for current app.

```
public class DSContext:DbContext
{
   public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

I can access and use models from both data libraries in MVC app (and it works), but how to tell `membership provider` to use the same `DBContext` that I use in MVC app something like this?

```cs
var pUser = SomeDBContext.Users.Find(Username);
return new MembershipUser(...Set properties from pUser...);
```

`SomeDBContext` can be any `DbContext` that has property `Users` with type `User` from first class library.

**After some trial and error got the solution to this**
Feel free to comment - as I do not know how correct it is.

1. Class library

```cs
public class User
{
   [Required]
   [Key]
   public string UserName{get; set;}
   public string PassWord{ get; set;}
}

public class UserContext : DbContext
{
   public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

2. Provider - the key was to make it abstract

```cs
public abstract class STMembershipProvider : ExtendedMembershipProvider
```

and to add abstract property

```cs
public abstract CL.UserContext DB { get; }

public override bool ValidateUser(string username, string password)
{

    User dbuser = DB.Users.Find(username);

    if (dbuser != null)
    {
        if (dbuser.PassWord == password) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

3. In MVC application create local `DbContext` what inherits from class library `DbContext` and local provider that inherits from `MembershipProvider` in the library.

```cs
public class EFContext:CL.UserContext
{

}
```

and

```cs
public class LocalMp:MP.STMembershipProvider
{
    public override CL.UserContext DB
    {
        get
        {
            return new EF.Models.EFContext();
        }
    }
}
```

and that did the magic :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use general library for user rights and access you have to design an abstract layer which will be used by your membership provider. Since DBContext is directly connected to specific business domain and you want to use a general library for access and authorization you need to map specific objects of your project to that abstract layer. I can imagine that such abstract layer should allow to operate on entities (or tabels) in a following way:

1. Get a specific instance of business object
2. Map it (or cast it) to abstract layer security object A
3. Run your membership provider to do security work on object A
4. Use output to decide any action (allow access, restrict access)...

Hope this will help.

Comment: How do I access provider to cast my object to this abstract object?

Comment: Please, post some details of code from your membership provider.

Comment: I have DbContext that have DBSet<Users> Users {get;set;} defined in MVC app. I need to know how to access this DbSet from `MembershipProvider`. Users is defined in first library and both MVC app and provider has reference to it.

Comment: I do not want to have different MembershipProvider for each MVC application, thats why I need access to DBContext from MVC app.

Comment: Finnaly got it working - Your first answer got me in the right dirrection, so can You reedit this anser, so I can set it resolved - I`ll add full solution in question itself - do not know how correct it is thou. :(

Comment: I restored previous answer. I am happy that it help you.